# Increase <li> tag hovering using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble to set my `<li>` tag hovering height. Below is my jsfiddle of my html and css code. Can anyone help me with this. I would be happy if there is someone to help me with this.

[My menubar jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eve8nsau/)

Below is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>Home</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
   <div id="logo">

   </div>
   <div id="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li id="left"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li id="left"><a href="#home">About Us</a></li>
        <li id="left"><a href="#home">Events</a></li>
        <li id="left"><a href="#home">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li id="right"><a href="#home">Login</a></li>
      </ul>

   </div>
   <div id="imgbanner">

   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

This is my css code:

```
#logo {
   border-bottom: 2px solid black;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100px;
}

#navigation {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
    color: #888;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%; 
}

#navigation ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

#navigation li {
    display: inline;
    /*padding: 20px;*/
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s; 
 }

 #navigation li:hover {
    background-color: rgb( 251,184,41);
/*  padding: 20px;
*/
}

#navigation a {
    color: #026475;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 56px;
    padding: 0 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*#imgbanner {
   position: absolute;
   border: 2px solid black; 
}
 */
 ul #right {
    float: right;
 }

li #right{
    float: left;
}
```

Once I run this current code, I can hover in both of my `<li>` tags but then the height is different for the last `<li>` tag

Comment: Like this? [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eve8nsau/2/) Change `li` to `inline-block` and `a` to `block` as there is no reason to have it as `inline-block`.

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/eve8nsau/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/eve8nsau/1/

change

```
#navigation li {
    display: inline;
    ...
```

into

```
#navigation li {
    display: inline-block;
    ...
```

now, you may notice a small gap between list-items but you can remove it using various techniques [already discussed on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

---

**Preview** (on `hover`)

[image]

Comment: Also there is no reason anymore to have `a` as `inline-block`. Should be just `block`. +1

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you're only adding "float: left" to the last `<li>`, I would change it into:

```
 li {
     float: left;
 }
```